# How to fix: 'QNetworkReply::SslHandshakeFailedError' on Android device

Tags: android, c++, qt, https

I try to access a Server with QNetworkAccessManager and a QNetworkRequest and I receive the error: QNetworkReply::SslHandshakeFailedError on Android device.

I have already compiled the OpenSSL Library for android and added the library to my Qt project [ https://github.com/ekke/android-openssl-qt ]

I am using Qt 5.12, Andoird NDK 19, Android API 26

I added the following ssl configuration:

```cpp
sslConf = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
sslConf.setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);
sslConf.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
sslConf.setCaCertificates({});
QSslConfiguration::setDefaultConfiguration(sslConf);
netAccessManager.setStrictTransportSecurityEnabled(false);
```

Try to get the response:

```cpp
QNetworkRequest nr;
nr.setSslConfiguration(this->sslConf);
nr.setUrl(QUrl("https://myserver.com/services/abc"));

//HTTP Basic authentication header value: base64(username:password)
QString concatenated = username + ":" + pw;
QByteArray data = concatenated.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
QString headerData = "Basic " + data;
nr.setRawHeader("Authorization", headerData.toLocal8Bit());

QNetworkReply *reply = netAccessManager.get(nr);
reply->ignoreSslErrors();

QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(const QList<QSslError>)),
                 this, SLOT(sslError(const QList<QSslError>)));
```

The code works fine on Linux, and on Linux the error: QNetworkReply::SslHandshakeFailedError comes up.

Comment: Could you print more details about the errors using `QString QSslError::errorString() const` ?

Comment: The connected slot ```sslError()``` is not invoked. I get the error message from the connected SIGNAL ```finished```. The QNetworkReply::SslHandshakeFailedError is the return value of ```reply->error()```

Comment: don't `reply->ignoreSslErrors();` if you want to investigate further

Comment: I removed ```reply->ignoreSslErrors();``` - still the same result.

Comment: look at this example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-http-httpwindow-cpp.html - it's pretty straightforward to print ssl errors

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried the example with the openSSL Lib that I compiled and I also tried the library from: https://github.com/orangefour/android-openssl with the same result, SSL Handshake failed in ```httpFinished``` 
I did not change the defaultURL, but still have the same error.